# Is there any augmenting graph algorithm available for finding maximum independent set problem in K1,4-free graph in polynomial time

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, independent-set, graph-classes

$K_{1,4}$-free graph is the graph with no induced subgraph of the form $K_{1,4}$
[image]

An augmenting graph $H$ for $S$ (which is an independent set) is an induced bipartite subgraph of $G$, where $H = (B, W, E)$ and the following properties hold:

1. $B\subseteq V(G)\setminus S$ and $W\subseteq S$.
2. $|B|>|W|$.
3. $N(B)\cap S\subseteq W$.

An independent set $S$ in a graph $G$ is maximum if and only if
there are no augmenting graphs for $S$.

Comment: No. "Let $H$ be a connected graph which is neither a path nor a subdivision of
the claw. Then MIS is NP-hard in $H$-free graphs."
This is stated as Theorem 1 in the following link: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.04620.pdf, which cite the paper: "The effect of local constraints on the complexity of determination of the graph independence number." by V. Alekseev. which is in Russian.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "augmenting graph algorithm"? Do you demand that such an algorithm should run in polynomial time?

Comment: @TheHolyJoker In this case NP-hardness simply follows from NP-hardness on cubic graphs.

Comment: @TheHolyJoker thanks for mentioning this paper, this states that in theorem 2 that MIS on K1,4-free is W[1]-hard. Is it safe to say that no augmenting graph algorithm exists for this problem?

Comment: @ChristianKomusiewicz It means that after finding initial independent set, the graph should have some subgraph which we called augmenting graph. By finding such subgraph structures we can swap vertices in the independent set to them which are not. Identification of such augmenting graphs should be also done in polynomial time.

Comment: Ok, then I suggest that you add this fact (polynomial running time) to the question? Btw, W[1]-hardness for $K_{1,4}$ free graphs suggests that not only that there is no polynomial-time augmenting graph algorithm but also that there is no such algorithm with FPT running time for the parameter $|H|$. Finally, what you call an augmenting graph is also called an improving swap $B\cup W$ in the local search literature.

Comment: @ChristianKomusiewicz thanks for the suggestions